# Is there a way to create an array which values are conditioned by the values of another array?

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, coefficients, energy

I have an array of values called E representing Energy values

```
E = np.arange(0.1, 101, 0.1)
```

And I want to create a group of arrays called a0, a1, a2, a3, being those coefficients that vary depending on the value of the energy, so I want to do something similar to this:

```
for item in E:
  if item <= 1.28:
      a3, a2, a1, a0 = 0, -8.6616, 13.879, -12.104 
  elif 1.28<item<10:
      a3, a2, a1, a0 = -0.186, 0.428, 2.831, -8.76
  elif item >=10:
      a3, a2, a1, a0 = 0, -0.0365, 1.206, -4.76
```

This code does not return any mistake, but I do not know how to create lists or arrays with the same length as the E (energy array), with every array containing the values of the coefficients fo specific energy values, so I would really appreciate your help!

Best regards!

Comment: use `a0 = [] ... a0.append(new_value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

constants = [[ 0, -8.6616, 13.879, -12.104 ],
             [ 0.186, 0.428, 2.831, -8.76 ],
             [ 0, -0.0365, 1.206, -4.76 ]]

constants = np.array(constants)

E = np.arange(0.1, 101, 0.1)

bins = np.digitize(E, [1.28, 10])

a0 = np.choose(bins, constants[:, 3])
a1 = np.choose(bins, constants[:, 2])
a2 = np.choose(bins, constants[:, 1])
a3 = np.choose(bins, constants[:, 0])
```

Comment: Beautiful way to solve this, I've never heard of numpy's `digitize` function before !

Comment: Wow thank you! what a nice way to solve it, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this fast, you can use boolean arrays as follows :

```
bool_array_1 = (E <= 1.28)
bool_array_2 = (E > 1.28) & (E < 10)
bool_array_3 = (E >= 10)

a3 = -0.186 * bool_array_2 
a2 = -8.6616 * bool_array_1 + 0.428 * bool_array_2 + (-0.0365) * bool_array_3 
a1 = 13.879 * bool_array_1 + 2.831 * bool_array_2 + 1.206 * bool_array_3 
a0 = -12.104 * bool_array_1 + (-8.76) * bool_array_2 + (-4.76) * bool_array_3
```

As for example if `a = 1.5` and `b = np.array([False, True, False, True])`, then `a * b` produces `array([0, 1.5, 0, 1.5])`

Comment: thank you for the help! I appreciate it :)